Remote memory profiling w/ Visual Studio
Is there a way to profile memory of a native C++ application on a remote machine where VS is not installed?
Per MSFT document below, remote tool is installed on the remote Windows and VSDiagnostics.exe should be used. There are also two relevant agent DLLs (MemoryProfilerCollectionAgent and NativeMemoryCollectionAgent). However, there are no sample agent config JSON files for them.
And I don't seem to find any page that introduces these two agents. So hence to ask:

Is memory profiling actually supported remotely (by VSDiagnostics.exe)?
If yes, how can I get the CLSID of them and write my own agent config files for them?

VSDiagnostics.exe start <id> /attach:<pid> /loadConfig:<configFile>




Regarding the questions you raised, please refer to the following suggestions:
1: Memory analysis can be supported remotely by using VSDiagnostics.exe.
2: Regarding the CLSID of the agent, you can usually find it in the registry. You can check the InProcServer32 key under the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\ or HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ path, where the DLL files associated with the CLSID are usually listed. If you know the name of the broker, you can try searching the registry for the corresponding CLSID.
Regarding this issue, there is a similar post for reference: How to find a DLL given a CLSID?
3: Regarding how to create the configuration file, just create it in the same format as the third picture you uploaded.
4: Once you have the configuration file, you can use the following command to start VSDiagnostics.exe and attach to the remote process:
VSDiagnostics.exe start  /attach: /loadConfig:

we checked the entire registry. They are not present anywhere on any of our machines.

Vote you anyway!

Thanks for your vote. After I checked the MSFT document again, I think you may have misunderstood the usage. This path: Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio<version><sku>\Team Tools\DiagnosticsHub\Collector\AgentConfigs, contains configuration files such as CpuUsage, DotNetObjectAlloc, Base/Low/High. And about this command: VSDiagnostics.exe start  /attach: /loadConfig:, we should use the above configuration files to get the corresponding information.

Yes, the AgentConfig contains the sample config files only, per MSFT. Agent for native memory profiling is missing, which is the question here.

I noticed that the DotNetObjectAlloc profile (Basic/Low) corresponds to the data collected for the .NET Object Allocation Tool, which is used to understand how much memory your app uses and which code paths allocate the most memory. You can check to see if it meets your needs.

That is managed. We are looking for memory profiling for native applications (C++). I believe that is what "NativeMemoryCollectAgent.dll" does. But there is no agent config for it.

Yes, NativeMemoryCollectAgent.dll is a memory analysis tool for C++ native applications. The CLSID of the dll is required to create the corresponding agent configuration file. If the corresponding CLSID of this dll cannot be searched in the registry, I suggest it would be more appropriate for you to report this issue to DC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest
